# Which test statistic is more effective in testing the variance of a normal variable?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, hypothesis-testing

Most of the time, to do hypothesis tests is to follow the tedious processes given on statistics textbooks. But recently I find that there are, in general, **more than several** test statistics that can be used to test the same hypothesis. To give an example consider the following test.

> $n$ samples of the random variable $X$ are given. Null Hypothesis $H_0:X\sim N(\mu,\sigma_0^2)$. Alternative Hypothesis $H_1:X\sim N(\mu,\sigma_1^2)$. $\mu$ and $\sigma_i$ are known. $\sigma_0<\sigma_1$.

If we *follow the textbooks*, then we should use the $\chi$-square distribution, and the test statistic is the variance of the sample(times $n$ divided by $\sigma_0$). But the following test is also appropriate.

> Let $\bar{X}$ be the sample mean. If $|\bar{X}-\mu|<c$ then accept $H_0$. Otherwise accept $H_1$. $c$ is chosen according to the level of significance of the test, $\alpha$.

This is an appropriate test because the condition $|\bar{X}-\mu|<c$ is more likely to be satisfied under $H_0$ than under $H_1$. (**Many other test statistics** are also appropriate for the same reason.) The test, however, has one shortcoming: the probability of making a type II error, $\beta$, is independent of $n$, which means it doesn't decrease as sample size increases.

**Therefore I wonder which test statistic is the best in this situation.** There is some simple criteria of how good a test statistic is. In this case, for example, we can say that for $n=100$ and $\alpha=0.05$, the smaller the minimum value of $\sigma_1/\sigma_0$ required to make $\beta\leq 0.05$, the better the test statistic.

Also, **how can we make sure that the test given on the textbook is the best test, and there are no better alternatives?**

Since this question might be too broad, I would be glad if anyone could give a specific example(like the one above) to illustrate the general idea. Also, **are there any books or articles that discuss this topic in detail?**

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390415/which-test-statistics-is-better-in-the-hypothesis-test-for-variance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, with a simple null and alternative hypothesis, the aim is to keep the probability of wrongly rejecting the null hypothesis (a Type I error) below a particular value (the *significance* level of the test) and then minimise the probability of wrongly failing to reject the null hypothesis (a Type II error), i.e. maximising the *power* of the test. Some tests are more powerful than others for the same level of significance

So let's take your suggested test statistics with some arbitrary specific numbers: $H_0: X_i \sim \mathcal N(100,4)$ against $H_1: X_i \sim \mathcal N(100,9)$ with a sample size of $10$ aiming for a significance level of $0.05$, and compare:

- Test A based on  $\frac1{\sigma^2} \sum\limits_i (X_i-\mu)^2 \sim \chi^2_n$: reject $H_0$ if $\frac1{4} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} (X_i-100)^2 \gt 18.307$.  This has a probability of rejection of about $0.6155$ if $H_1$ is correct but $0.05$ if $H_0$ is correct
- Test B based on  $ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\left(\bar{X}-\mu\right) \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$: reject $H_0$ if $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{4}} \bigg|\bar{X}-100\bigg| \gt 1.96$.  This has a probability of rejection of about $0.1913$ if $H_1$ is correct but $0.05$ if $H_0$ is correct

So Test A is more than three times as powerful as Test B in this particular case (seen another way, Test A is less than half as likely to make Type II errors), and in that sense Test A is a better test

With larger $n$ the distinction is even greater: with $n=100$ the power of Test A using $\chi^2_{100}$ rises to about $0.9999$ while, as you say, the power of Test B stays constant, at about $0.1913$

The [Neyman–Pearson_lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) can point to the [uniformly most powerful test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) for simple hypotheses